# javascript: history.go(-1) doesnt work for the whole window

Tags: javascript, return, browser-history

i have an unusual problem. I have a page which contains an iframe, which is controlled by the dropdown. So selection of the dropdown loads different iframes. Anyway - on the bottom I have a button to return to the previous page (I mean the whole page, not previously loaded iframe on that page).

```
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">
```

Unfortunately it also includes the history of these iframes, so when I click on that button, it loads up the previous iframe instead of taking me back.

Here is how to explain it well:

1. go to this page: [Click here](http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/here.html)
2. go to the hyperlink on that page
3. make couple of selections from the drop down (play with it)
4. click the return button on the very bottom of the page.

I want it to take me back to the first page (here.html), not go back to the previously loaded iframe on 1.html.

I have to use javascript history.go or similar script. I can't use direct link to here.html, as this page is a part of many other pages, so when the user clicks return, he is forwarded to his specific landing page. 
I greatly appreciate any help.

It's a life-saving question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript back button for iframe parent window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993244/javascript-back-button-for-iframe-parent-window)

Comment: @Domi unfortunately this didn't help me. still the same. it reopens the previously selected iframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the newly `iframe` before sending browser back to the actual page.

Add click event on the return link

HTML:

`<a id="return_link" href="#">`

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#return_link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#iframeId').remove();
        window.location = document.referrer;
       });
    });
```

Comment: this one doesn't take me back anywhere unfortunately.

Comment: Where did you place the javascript? and did you change the anchor attributes?

Comment: i placed the javascript in a separate js file. does it make a difference? i can place it inside the html file if that will help. how should I do that? Thanks :)

Comment: I think you are executing the event when `DOM` is'nt ready check edit.

Comment: here is where I placed the script: http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/js/selection2.js  its after the previous script which adds the iframeId

Comment: Thats not my code where you get the code?
Please copy exact script from above change `#selector` to `#return_link` and make change to your return anchor tag in html with mine above.

Comment: please check now. i have to keep that code as it's responsible for selecting the iframe from the dropdown. i have placed your code below but it doesnt work now. http://content.captive-portal.com/campaigns/sky/1.html

Comment: is thhere anything else i can do to maintain the dropdown selection working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42192/discussion-between-piotr-ciszewski-and-rahil-wazir)

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski See edited just place `e.preventDefault()` right after the `function(e) {` and add `e` parameter in `function`

Comment: Works absolutely great on all platforms and browsers. thank you @RahilWazir

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.referer`

```
var referrer =  document.referrer;
window.location = referrer;
```

Check if it works !

```
<a href="javascript: window.location = document.referrer;">
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. it takes me back but i cant access that page anymore...

Answer (score 0):

try this , Just remove extra spaces from statements.

**href="javascript:history.go(-1)**

Comment: this is not an issue.