# Go to parent history from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

When inside an iframe and clicking a button, is it possible to go back to the parent history (**the history of the parent page**)?

From within the iframe:

```
$('#back').click(function(){
    parent.history.back(); // leave the iframe and go back to the perant history
});
```

Comment: Seems like it takes me to the history of the iframe, inside the iframe

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2993363/3168107.

Comment: Thanks @Shikkediel that was helpful. I didn't think there would be any difference between the history.back and the history.go, apparently there is